# Emplace a pointer to a multimap of shared_ptr's doesn't work

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, multimap, emplace

Vector works properly

```
Header
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SceneNode>> subnodes_m;

Definition
void CompositeSceneNode::AddChild(SceneNode* subnode_p)
{
    subnodes_m.emplace_back(subnode_p);
}
```

Multimap doesn't

```
Header
std::multimap<unsigned int, std::shared_ptr<SceneNode>> subnodes_m;

Definition
void CompositeSceneNode::AddChild(SceneNode* subnode_p, unsigned int layerIndex)
{
    subnodes_m.emplace(layerIndex, subnode_p);
}
```

I get following error:

```
error C2664: 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair(const unsigned int &,const _Ty2 &)' :
cannot convert parameter 2 from 'RendererD3DWrapper::SceneNode *'
to 'const std::shared_ptr<_Ty> &'
```

Anybody has a clue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't construct a `std::pair<T1,T2>` with arguments of types `U` and `V` if there is no **implicit** conversion of `U` into `T1`, and `V` into `T2`. In your case, there is no implicit conversion of `SceneNode*` into `std::shared_ptr<SceneNode>`.

From the C++ standard:

> #### § 20.3.2 Class template `pair` `[pairs.pair]`
>
> ```
> template<class U, class V> constexpr pair(U&& x, V&& y);
> ```
>
> 7. *Requires:* `is_constructible<first_type, U&&>::value` is `true` and `is_constructible<second_type, V&&>::value` is `true`.
> 8. *Effects:* The constructor initializes `first` with `std::forward<U>(x)` and `second` with `std::forward<V>(y)`.
> 9. *Remarks:* If `U` is not implicitly convertible to `first_type` or `V` is not implicitly convertible to `second_type` this **constructor shall not participate in overload resolution**.

Having said that, you can't initialize a `std::pair<T1,T2>` like below (as `emplace` builds *in-place* a `std::pair<key_type, mapped_type>` known as `value_type` of `std::multimap`):

```
std::pair<unsigned int, std::shared_ptr<SceneNode>> p( 1, new SceneNode );
```

because the constructor of `std::shared_ptr<T>` taking a raw pointer (declared below) is an `explicit` constructor, hence the error you encounter:

> #### § 20.9.2.2 Class template `shared_ptr` `[util.smartptr.shared]`
>
> ```
> [...]
>
> template<class Y> explicit shared_ptr(Y* p);
> ```

In C++11 you should **either** build a `std::shared_ptr<T>` before calling `emplace`:

```
subnodes_m.emplace(layerIndex, std::shared_ptr<SceneNode>(subnode_p));
```

, **or** you can forward arguments to the constructors of pair's elements (rather than forwarding them to the constructor of `std::pair<T1,T2>` itself), with a [***piecewise construction***](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/piecewise_construct):

```
subnodes_m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct
                 , std::forward_as_tuple(layerIndex)
                 , std::forward_as_tuple(subnode_p));
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd8a223498134a55)

> *Why does it work with `std::vector` of `std::shared_ptr`'s then?*

The `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>::emplace_back` member function forwards the arguments of `emplace_back` to the constructor of `std::shared_ptr<T>`, satisfying the explicit context requirement. In case of a `map` and a `multimap`, the emplaced type is a `pair` which has the constructor that forwards arguments further into its elements disabled if the conversion between argument's and parameter's types of those elements is not implicit (as cited above).

Comment: Why can't you use `piecewise_construct` in C++11?

Comment: @JonathanWakely: hmm.. I thought this is C++14's feature

Comment: @Piotr S.: Very descriptive answer. Must analyse this piecewise_construct, as its new to me. Thanks!